# Configuring Haproxy to allow http CRUD (rewrite rules)

Tags: php, laravel, rest, load-balancing, haproxy

I'm using haproxy to loadbalance and get high availability of my (RESTFUL)API, the problem I'm facing is: I can't send REST requests to the API. 
I mean haproxy does not support REST API by default and I've figured that I should configure an `ACL` to make it work, but I couldn't find anything about configuring RESTFUL Support and enabaling http rewrite rules for haproxy.

MY API is based on laravel framework.

For example If I hit `192.168.1.139/login` I get 404 error message. the only route which is working is `/` Which shows the user "you are not logged in." message.

This is haproxy configuration :

```
listen http_front
        bind *:80
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats uri /haproxy?stats
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        #acl api_exp hdr(host) -i domain_name.com
        #use_backend api_servers if api_exp
        default_backend api_servers

backend api_servers
        balance roundrobin
        server replica1 192.168.100.110:80 check
        server replica2 192.168.100.111:80 check
```

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about configuring servers. ServerFault.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for guiding me. should I remove my question here ?

Comment: You can flag it for migration by the moderators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit strange but I've solved my problem with this configuration :

```
defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect  5000
    timeout client  100s
    timeout server  100s


listen ha-www
bind 0.0.0.0:80
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    stats realm Strictly\ Private
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server app-www-1 192.168.100.110:80 check
    server app-www-2 192.168.100.111:80 check
```